# Create rows in a linked table postgresql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have a table called problems:

```
  id int NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
  from_id int DEFAULT NULL,
  to_id int DEFAULT NULL
```

Also, I have a table called solutions:

```
  problem_id int REFERENCES problems(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  cost varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
```

I would like to have postgres create a row automatically upon INSERT to problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for TRIGGERS that are stored procedures that will run automatically whenever you insert values into the problems table. [Read more on Triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-trigger.html)

```
CREATE TRIGGER AUTO_INSERT_TO_SOLUTIONS 
AFTER INSERT ON PROBLEMS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SOLUTIONS(NEW.id,NULL);
END;
/
```